# How to make pointer to specialized variant of templated member function?

Tags: c++, templates, c++03, pointer-to-member

There is a templated member function in some class `Foo`

```
template <typename T>
void Foo::bar(std::string &, const T&);
```

How to make a make pointer to following specialized variant of this function?

```
void Foo::bar<std::string>(std::string &, const std::string&);
```

There is like what I mean

```
typedef void (Foo::*Bar_t)(std::string &, const std::string&);
Bar_t stringedBar = &Foo::bar<std::string> // ???
```

Comment: Have you actually tried some syntax and got an error?

Comment: @PlasmaHH - Thank you. There is some reduced sample. I'll recheck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly as you have written it.

```
typedef void (Foo::*Bar_t)(std::string &, const std::string&);
Bar_t stringedBar = &Foo::bar<std::string>;
```

[See here](http://ideone.com/jNmCIB) for an example.